# How to force link from iframe to be opened in the parent window

Tags: html, iframe, hyperlink, html-target

I need to open the link in the same parent page, instead of open it in a new page.

note : The `iframe` and parent page are **the same domain**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load iframe links into parent window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712880/load-iframe-links-into-parent-window)

Answer (score 714, accepted):

I found the best solution was to use the **base** tag.  Add the following to the head of the page in the iframe:

```
<base target="_parent">
```

This will load all links on the page in the parent window.  If you want your links to load in a new window, use:

```
<base target="_blank">
```

[Browser Support](https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_elements_base)

Comment: How does this fare cross-browser?

Comment: seems buggy in IE, might need to be placed above other things in the head of the page, see http://ow.ly/d6i5Q

Comment: @KristopherIves Thanks! I've updated my answer with a link to SitePoint documentation on browser compatibility.

Comment: If you use `<base>`, make sure to put it before any other URL reference (`href= src=` etc.)

Comment: Awesome, I needed to use `<base target="_self" />`. Other than that thank you for laying out the initial solution. :)

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. The OP didn't say he needs to redirect *all* of the links in the parent. The correct basic answer is the one of @nnevala.

Comment: @Wilf I was not quite correct: ;) `<base target>` should come before any `<a href>`, since it sets the default browsing context for following links; `<base href>` should come before any URL reference (`<* href>` `<* src>` `<form action>` `<object data>`…) since it sets the base URL against which relative URLs are resolved.

Comment: why did you answer this question a year **after** I had answered it, with the exact same answer? but you were picked. this is so strange.

Comment: I think it's because your answer opens the link in a new window, whereas mine opens it in the parent window of the iframe, which was the original question. Sorry to steal your thunder!

Comment: Be sure to set your `<iframe>`'s `sandbox` attribute to `allow-top-navigation` to give this solution to the best chance to work. I learned this the hard way today. Make my pain your gain.

Comment: Note that the `<base` tag has no closing according to the specification https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata#the-base-element so it should be `<base target="_parent" >`

Comment: sitepoint link in this answer is broken. Better to link to w3.org.

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be `_top` rather than `_parent`?

Comment: not sure that this is a good solution imho.. I've figured out with this question and wrote post  here https://alfilatov.com/posts/how-to-open-links-from-iframe/

Answer (score 178):

Use target-attribute:

```
<a target="_parent" href="http://url.org">link</a>
```

Comment: `<base target="_blank">` is ok, but the question here is about one link, not about changing behavior of all links on iframe. For me this is the correct answer.

Comment: What about opening the link a new tab of the parent? The example above opens the link in the same tab of the parent window.

Comment: opening in same tab as required. not in new tab. works fine

Answer (score 44):

With JavaScript:

```
window.parent.location.href= "http://www.google.com";
```

Comment: this solution worked properly for me. I had a button tag from which on click I wanted the same page to reload with a new URL. The button was present in an iFrame so needed the page to reload with the new URL and not the iFrame. Using window.parent worked wonders. Thanks for this!!

Answer (score 40):

**You can use any options**

**in case of only parent page:**

if you want to open **all link** into parent page or parent iframe, then you use following code in head section of iframe:

`<base target="_parent" />`

**OR**

if you want to open a **specific link** into parent page  or parent iframe, then you use following way:

```
<a target="_parent" href="http://specific.org">specific Link</a>
<a  href="http://normal.org">Normal Link</a>
```

**OR**

**in case of nested iframe:**

If want to open **all link** into browser window (redirect in browser url), then  you use following code in head section of iframe:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        $("a").click(function(){
            top.window.location.href=$(this).attr("href");
            return true;
        })
    })
</script>
```

**OR**

if you want to open a **specific link** into  browser window (redirect in browser url), then you use following way:

```
<a  href="http://specific.org"   target="_top" >specific Link</a>
```

or

```
<a  href="javascript:top.window.location.href='your_link'">specific Link</a>
<a  href="javascript:top.window.location.href='http://specific.org'">specific Link</a>
<a  href="http://normal.org">Normal Link</a>
```

Comment: Good answer, I needed to just use this for a specific link, yet the accepted answer only describes how to change the target for all links on the page. Thanks

Answer (score 20):

There's a HTML element called [`base`](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_base.asp) which allows you to:

> Specify a default URL and a default target for all links on a page:

```
<base target="_blank" />
```

By specifying `_blank` you make sure all links inside the *iframe* will be opened outside.

Comment: is this inherited in nested iframes ?

Answer (score 7):

Try `target="_parent"` **attribute** inside the `anchor tag`.

Comment: i try this , is open in new window

Comment: Try target="_top". The iframe might contain nested iframes? Or the actual link is opened by javascript on onclick event?

Answer (score 7):

As noted, you could use a target attribute, but it was technically deprecated in XHTML. That leaves you with using javascript, usually something like `parent.window.location`.

Comment: [The `target` attribute is no longer deprecated](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html#a.attrs.target).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite the link you posted now 404s.

Comment: @Dan: aha, yes thank you. Fresh link: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/links.html#links-created-by-a-and-area-elements

Answer (score 7):

If you are using iframe in your webpage you might encounter a problem while changing the whole page through a HTML hyperlink (anchor tag) from the iframe. There are two solutions to mitigate this problem.

Solution 1. You can use target attribute of anchor tag as given in the following example.

```
<a target="_parent" href="http://www.kriblog.com">link</a>
```

Solution 2. You can also open a new page in parent window from iframe with JavaScript.

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.parent.location.href='http://www.kriblog.com';">
```

Remember ⇒ `target="_parent"` has been deprecated in XHTML, but it is still supported in HTML 5.x.

More can be read from following link 
http://www.kriblog.com/html/link-of-iframe-open-in-the-parent-window.html

Answer (score 6):

**The most versatile and most cross-browser solution is to avoid use of the "base" tag, and instead use the target attribute of the "a" tags:**

```
<a target="_parent" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
```

The `<base>` tag is less versatile and browsers are inconsistent in their requirements for its placement within the document, requiring more cross-browser testing. Depending on your project and situation, it can be difficult or even totally unfeasible to achieve the ideal cross-browser placement of the `<base>` tag.

Doing this with the `target="_parent"` attribute of the `<a>` tag is not only more browser-friendly, but also allows you to distinguish between those links you want to open in the iframe, and those you want to open in the parent.

Answer (score 4):

`<a target="parent">` will open links in a new tab/window ... `<a target="_parent">` will open links in the parent/current window, without opening new tabs/windows. Don't_forget_that_underscore!

Answer (score 2):

Yah I found

```
<base target="_parent" />
```

This useful for open all iframe links open in iframe.

And

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        top.window.location.href=$(this).attr("href");
        return true;
    })
})
```

This we can use for whole page or specific part of page.

Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
   <script type="text/javascript"> // if site open in iframe then redirect to main site
        $(function(){
             if(window.top.location != window.self.location)
             {
                top.window.location.href = window.self.location;
             }
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `target="_top"`

```
<a href="http://example.com" target="_top">
   This link will open in same but parent window of iframe.
</a>
```

Comment: isn't `"_top"` the same as `"_parent"` ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target

Answer (score -2):

I have found simple solution

```
<iframe class="embedded-content" sandbox="allow-top-navigation"></iframe>
```

allow-top-navigation
Allows the iframe to change parent.location.
For more info https://javascript.info/cross-window-communication