# Facebook login like Pinterest style

Tags: facebook-login, pinterest

I want to integrate Pinterest style Facebook login to my website. Is there a way to do this?

[pinterest facebook login style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBVMY.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution, but it's certainly not optimal. I found that Pinterest uses this endpoint to generate it's nice button: facebook.com/v2.7/plugins/login_button.php ; however, the generated output seems to be tied into the Pinterest Facebook application ID only (I tried inputting my ID but only received a standard login button as per Facebook documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web#loginbutton)).

So my hacky solution presented comes from combining ScottyG's answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317917/use-iframe-as-a-link) with the iframe taken from the Pinterest site to get the following:

```
<div style="position:relative;">
    <iframe name="f34219de7beb196" width="268px" height="50px" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" scrolling="no" title="fb:login_button Facebook Social Plugin" src="https://www.facebook.com/v2.7/plugins/login_button.php?app_id=274266067164&channel=https%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2Fr%2FiPrOY23SGAp.js%3Fversion%3D42%23cb%3Df5f46a0766a3f%26domain%3Dau.pinterest.com%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fau.pinterest.com%252Ff16edab41b7ba12%26relation%3Dparent.parent&container_width=268&locale=en_US&scope=public_profile%2Cemail%2Cuser_likes%2Cuser_about_me%2Cuser_birthday%2Cuser_friends&sdk=joey" class="" style="border: none; visibility: visible; width: 268px; height: 50px;"></iframe>
    <a href="#" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; display:inline-block; width: 268px; height: 50px; z-index:5;"></a>
</div>
```

Where here you can replace the anchor's href to whichever url you need if you are building a server-side Oauth dance like I am planning to do (alternatively you could register the Facebook javascript api's *FB.login()* call to the onclick here).

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/rw9f7jxj/

Note: I didn't test all browsers but it worked for me in both Safari and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out what the links mean in the answer above, so I assume that Facebook removed these pages already. Just in case anybody else ends up here, there's a section for creating a login button with "Continue as {NAME}" option on Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button