# Select Random URL and display in Embed window

Tags: javascript, html

What I'm trying to achieve is have a random URL selected, then that URL's page displayed in an embed that you can then click and go to that page. I've been having trouble however and would appreciate any help. This is what I got so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var urls = new Array();
urls[0] = "https://www.google.com";
urls[1] = "https://www.yahoo.com";
urls[2] = "https://www.bing.com";

var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*urls.length);

window.location = urls[random];

<embed src="urls" style="width:500px; height: 300px;">
</script>
```

Comment: the `<embed>` tag can't be put inside the `<script>` tag. And then you should set the src attribute of the embed tag, not the window.location; that's the page itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many errors in your code, for example the fact that you set the location of the current window with `window.location = ...` instead of setting the URL of the `<iframe>`, or that you have HTML code inside your JS, etc.

In any case, you should chose the URL before and *then* add an `<iframe>` to the DOM and set its url. Here's an example:

```js
const urls = [
  'https://example.com',
  'https://example.org',
];

const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = urls[Math.floor(Math.random()*urls.length)];
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Comment: Alright, thank you so much... do you have any idea how you could make the window clickable with a redirect to that page?

Comment: There's already a question on SO detailing [how to use an iframe as a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317917/use-iframe-as-a-link)

Comment: wrap the `<embed>` tag in an `<a>` tag with the same url as href attribute.