# iframe's document issue

Tags: javascript, html

i have a div in an iframe document. when i click a link in an iframe's document, that div opens or pops-up on the screen with z-index value. Now what i want here is to open this div in the parent document not the in iframe's document. so, how can achieve this..?

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037839/how-to-force-link-from-iframe-to-be-opened-in-the-parent-window

Comment: @HaimEvgi really helpful.. thnx

Answer (score 0):

Put or create the div in the parent, e.g. `window.getElementById('someDivInTheParent').style.display='block'`
or

```
var div = document.createElement('div')

.
.
.
window.document.body.appendChild(div);
```