# Opening a specific link outside the iFrame

Tags: html, css, iframe, html-target

I have a specific part of my website that runs in an iFrame. Now in the webpage that is run inside the iFrame, I specified `<base target="_parent" />` for all links, and they all open inside the iFrame(so if I would link to my main website home page, it would open inside the iframe). Now I want one specific link to open outside of the iframe and inside of the normal parent webpage.

How do I force that one specific link to do that? Tried `target="_blank"` but still opens inside the iFrame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've come across this solution a while back and I've been using it ever since. Force the link with a Javascript function:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 function newWindow(){
   top.location.href = 'http://yourURL';};
</script>
<a href="javascript: newWindow();">YourLink</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using JavaScript:

```js
        parent.document.location = "http://www.google.com"
```

And if you are using HTML:

```html
        <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_top">Google</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the link `onclick="window.location = 'url.html';"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not working. Tried with both setting the href='url.html' and without the href='url.html'...Any other suggestions?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037839/how-to-force-link-from-iframe-to-be-opened-in-the-parent-window

Comment: Generally it is inadvisable to put inline JavaScript in your HTML.  Better practice would be to have this click event handler attached by a script after the DOM object (the link) has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

When I make menus I make an iframe inside my index.html:

```
<div id="nav">
     <iframe frameBorder="0" height="35px" width="950px" src="navframe.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

Then in the navframe.html these are my buttons:

```
<button type="button" onClick="window.parent.location='index.html'">
Home</button>

<button type="button" onClick="window.parent.location='contact.html'">
Contact</button>
```

that tend to work