# Redirection and frames

Tags: php, redirect, phpmyadmin, frame

I've been researching this topic for the past few hours with little success.  I wish to redirect from the content of a frame, to the parent of the frame using php.  .. The only reason I think it's possible is because I disabled javascript on my browser and phpMyAdmin was still able to redirect me when the session ran out of time.

I also realize it is most likely not possible, given that frames are a client-side thing, and php is not.

That in mind, I'm wondering how phpMyAdmin does it.  I do not wish for js to be required for my web application.

Answer (score 0):

If an iframe has links which looks like this:

```
<a href="somepage.php" target="_parent">Some page</a>
```

it should work, as long as both pages or on the same domain.

Alternatively, take a look at this answer: [How to force link from iframe to be opened in the parent window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037839/how-to-force-link-from-iframe-to-be-opened-in-the-parent-window)

Comment: While I thank you for the effort you put into this answer, it does not answer my question, as my question is how to redirect, not how to direct links.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood you. Based on what I know, to perform a serverside redirect, which redirects the parentframe is impossible without using javascript.

Comment: I figured as much, but if that's the case, my question then becomes.. how does phpMyAdmin do it?  I disabled my js and it was still able to redirect the parent.

Comment: That is interesting. What led up to the redirect? Did you perform any sort of action on the page?

Comment: Yes, if there is a long period of inactivity, and I click say.. a navigation link or a tab, it will redirect.  But both of these items are in frames, and the navigation link does have `<base target="frame_content" />`.