# How to open the redirected page from Iframe to open as a new tab in the parent window in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe, tabs

i currently have:

```
        String url = "../CustomerSettings/CustomerConfiguration.aspx?CustomerID=" + sqlCommand.Parameters["@ReturnCustomerID"].Value.ToString();

        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "myUniqueKey", "self.parent.location='"+url+"';", true);
```

this works great to redirect the parent page but I need it to open a new tab. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "myUniqueKey", "window.open(" + url + ",'_blank');", true);
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply..i tried that but no window opens anymore...keep in mind i want to open a tab in the PARENT window..i believe if that were to work, it would only open in the iframe

Comment: window.open often gets caught up by pop-up blockers. If the window.open isn't initiated by a direct user input like clicking a button this will cause a problem for many users.

Comment: Is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037839/how-to-force-link-from-iframe-to-be-opened-in-the-parent-window Which suggests applying <base target="_parent" /> to the parent page to force all links inside the iframe to open within the parent.

Comment: i used this and it works:

this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CustomerConfiguration", "window.focus();window.location='" + url + "';", true);

thanks for the replies, they gave me some insight on what to do

Comment: No problem.. Glad you sorted this!