# Load iframe links into parent window?

Tags: html, iframe

I have this iframe code:

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com" border="0" framespacing="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" scrolling="yes" width="100%" frameborder="0" height="100%"></iframe>
```

What i'm trying to do is..when i click any link in iframe page..then i will go to it and the page will load and i will getout from the current page to the iframe link as a new page.

Something like `target="_self"` - not like the normal iframe which will go to this link without any changes in browser itself.

Example :
iframe src : http://www.w3schools.com

When i click "Learn HTML" inside the iframe page..then i will go to http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp
and my browser URL will change to it too.

So i just clicked a link inside the iframe and i go to it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force link from iframe to be opened in the parent window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037839/how-to-force-link-from-iframe-to-be-opened-in-the-parent-window)

Answer (score 42):

Yes, you can use [**target="_parent"**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) to achieve this.

> "target="_parent" opens the linked document in the parent frame."

**Example:**

```
<a target="_parent" href="http://example.org">Click me!</a>
```

---

**Edit:**

If that's not working, you can try `_top`:

```
<a target="_top" href="http://example.org">Click me!</a>
```

Or `base target`:

```
<base target="_parent" />
```

Or `window.top.location` in JavaScript:

```
window.top.location = "http://example.com";
```

Comment: @user2203703 I don't understand, this answers the question. you use target parent on the link inside the iframe..

Comment: I want to leave my page which have the iframe and goout to the link which i clicked inside the iframe

Comment: @user2203703 Yes.. that is what this does. You can on the link inside the iframe and you get re-directed from the page with the iframe to the new page.

Comment: yes, it's really work with different domains but not work if the iframe for the same domain..any idea please ?

Comment: @user2203703 Try `target="_top"` or in javascript `window.top.location = "http://google.com";`

Comment: the jsfiddle provided by @daniel currently does not work because the iframe that jsfiddle is using does not have the token "allow-top-navigation" in its sandbox attribute and because the target attribute on the link has _parent instead of _top

Answer (score 16):

What you're looking for is `<a href="..." target="_parent">`

`_parent` will cause it to go to the parent frame

`_top` will cause it to go to the top-most level.

Either `_parent` or `_top` should work for your target.

Comment: Maybe I'm not clear on the question.  The page in the iframe ... do you have control over the HTML in that page, or is it a third-party site?  I updated my answer to include target=_top but of course that's assuming you have control over the contents of the frame.

Answer (score 7):

You can use javascript to add the target to the links dynamically, something like this.

```
function onLoadIF(frame)
{
    var elements = frame.getElementsByTagName('a'),
        len = elements.length;

    while( len-- ) {
        elements[len].target = "_parent";
    }
}
```

And then add onload="onLoadIF(this)" to the iframe.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, just add `target="_parent"` on the link and it load on main page.

Answer (score 3):

If site opens in iframe then redirect to main site

```
<script>
    if (window.top.location != window.self.location) {
        top.window.location.href = window.self.location;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That's a hack and it doesn't even answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

Working solution for mobile safari and all other sane browsers, through javascript.

Safari iframes block opening links, and if your iframes are nested with no control over them (e.g. loaded as a vendor etc), this is a working method.

```js
// https only
var redirLink = "https://www.google.com";
// create an anchor and simulate a click.
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.title = redirLink;
a.href = redirLink;
// only "_top" or "_parent" supported.
a.target = "_top"; 
// prevent the default behaviour of anchors and do the address change manually. This must be tied to user actions to work.
a.onclick="function(e){e.preventDefault();top.location.href=this.href}"
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

References:

1. [How can I open a link in a nested iframe in the original window they're placed in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33221661/how-can-i-open-a-link-in-a-nested-iframe-in-the-original-window-theyre-placed-i)