# target="_parent" is opening in a new tab

Tags: html, iframe, jsfiddle, frames

I have a link inside an `iframe` that I want to go to the parent window. I set the `target` to `_parent`, but it opens in an entirely new tab, instead of in the parent page.

```
<iframe>
    <a href="" target="_parent">go to parent window!</a>
</iframe>
```

This is in JSFiddle, so I thought maybe they were intentionally blocking `target="_parent"`, but I can't see how.

[Here's the link to the **JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/k38199k5/). Click on the button that says "Continue to next page of demo »" to see the behavior I'm describing.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your head

```
<base target="_parent" />
```

Comment: Does not work. That doesn't do anything different than `target="_parent"` in the anchor would anyway.

Comment: see if this link helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712880/load-iframe-links-into-parent-window

Comment: There was a suggestion for `_top` that held promise, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

just use `target="_self"` instead of `"_parent"`

http://jsfiddle.net/eapo/k38199k5/8/

Comment: That puts it inside the `iframe`.