# How can I open a link in a nested iframe in the original window they're placed in?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Been trying the following from within an iframe nested in another iframe:

```
<a href="https://example.com" target="_parent">Link</a>
<a href="https://example.com" target="_top">Link</a>
<a href="https://example.com" target="_self">Link</a>
```

However, they all open in new windows instead of in the window the iframes are in. How can I make sure the link opens in the top browser window?

Answer (score 1):

If you want that every link in the child page can be opened in the web page that hosts the iframe, then you could add this tag inside the child page:

```
<base target="_top" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `onclick` attribute

```
<a href="https://example.com" 
   onclick="function(e){e.preventDefault();top.location.href=this.href}">Link</a>
```

```html
<iframe src="data:text/html,<!doctype html><iframe src='data:text/html,<!doctype html><a href=https://example.com onclick=function(e){e.preventDefault();top.location.href=this.href}>Link</a>'></iframe>">
</iframe>
```