# How to force redirect to open in a new tab instead of a new window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, redirect

I use this script:

```
<div id="accesso" class="spalla_basic grigio_type clearfix">
    <iframe src="test.php" frameborder="0" width="257" height="160" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

In my homepage I have the above code. And when I press `yes` on the above block it will redirect to a new page.
**But my problem is**: when I click on this block, it redirect me to a new page but with in this block.

Comment: So when you press "Yes" it is running code in some other domain, not yours. So you have no control over what the "Yes" button does

Comment: no no.. from this little box when i pres yes is redirect from a new page.. but the redirect is only on this little box not in entire page.

Comment: Everything will happen in the iframe unless the other sites code forces a new tab

Comment: Have you tried what they suggest here?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712880/load-iframe-links-into-parent-window

Comment: Try this solution : [How to make all links in an iframe open in new tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22808065/how-to-make-all-links-in-an-iframe-open-in-new-tab)

Comment: ok.. ty for so many links.. but i dont know php/html/java so good.. im newbie.. can you make a example for me please?

Comment: Note, you **can't control** whether it opens in a tab or new window, this is solely up to the user and how (s)he set up their browser

Comment: thanks i solved. with 4 files :D ty for your time. respect

Comment: corrected grammar, and also make it more easily readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you basically want the page within iframe to escape the frame and load in a different tab after you click over the button ? Is that what you are trying to accomplish ?

Try adding the following code to the `<head>` section.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (top.location!= self.location){
        top.location = self.location
    }
</script>
```

The following is the HTML file with your iframe which loads your PHP code that has a button.

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="sample.php">
</body>
</html>
```

Suppose landing.php is the page that you get redirected to after clicking over the button. The JavaScript code should be incorporated in landing.php

```
<?php
echo "<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (top.location!= self.location){
        top.location = self.location
    }
</script>
</head>";

?>
```

Comment: i add this after i see <head> and nothing change.. i do something wrong? PS: im new with php/html/java etc..

Comment: one problem..in<iframe src="sample.php"> i add this <?php
echo "<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (top.location!= self.location){
        top.location = self.location
    }
</script>
</head>";

?> on sample.php ------------------------- but one problem.. now is redirect automatic without press the button.

Comment: Do you really have control on the landing page ? I mean the page that you get redirected to after pressing the button. We are considering 3 files here. First one is your HTML page. 2nd one is the php page that has a button in it. 3rd one is the landing page( the page you get redirected to after clicking the button). The JavaScript code should go on top of the landing page.

Comment: thanks i solved. with 4 files :D ty for your time. respect