# Tag a inside iframe not Working

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

For example,

```
<iframe src = "example.html">
  <a href = "https://www.yahoo.com/" target="_blank">
</iframe>
```

I want a new window(yahoo) to open but A Tag inside iframe not working.
Why??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load iframe links into parent window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712880/load-iframe-links-into-parent-window)

Answer (score 2):

The iframe tag loads the files inside of it sourced as src attribute. It only loads the `example.html` file from your directory.

If you still want to redirect to yahoo window, specify that tag elements in the `example.html`, otherwise make the `<iframe src= "https://www.yahoo.com/"> </iframe>`