# advertise on one wordpress site for woocommerce on another

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have multiple related wordpress sites. one of them has woocommerce.

is there a way to promote some of those products (maybe identified by category or new or something like that) on one of my non-woocommerce sites?

Like the way google adwords show products related to, but not actually productized on that site?

Thanks.

Comment: Possibly what could solve your problem is to create WooCommerce affiliate products on your websites. Find out more at https://woocommerce.com/videos/woocommerce-external-affiliate-product-overview/. Generally however this question is not well suited to SO so flagging to close. I recommend asking on a forum or subreddit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever thought about embedding iframe?
You have 2 choices, one is by using REST API as @tachb mentioned and the other one is by embedding iframe.
So you can make a custom products page which has products only without header and footer on the woocommerce site.
After that you can embed the page on the other sites as an iframe.
And please don't forget to add target="_parent" attribute to your all links in iframe content as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037839/how-to-force-link-from-iframe-to-be-opened-in-the-parent-window) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712880/load-iframe-links-into-parent-window).

Hope this will help you.

Comment: That's a good idea,  Thank you very much.  I will do this. it's easiest.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the REST API and grab the info you want from any site that can query the API.

Enable the API:
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/

Tech Docs:
http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/