# How can i open links in an iframe in the main window and not in the iframe?

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe, interactive

Lets say you have an iframe:

```
<iframe style="border-radius:15px;" width="190" height="450" 
     frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="5"
     marginwidth="10" src="../img/interactive_map/interactive_sverige.htm">
</iframe>
```

It has it source locally, which is a interactive map. The map contains links. The goal is to open the link in the window that you already are, not in the iframe itself (on the page).

Is this possible?

/Thnx

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037839/how-to-force-link-from-iframe-to-be-opened-in-the-parent-window

Comment: I did, but i have no clue how to or where to insert <base target="_parent" /> ? Why -3? What is wrong with this question? :(

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't adding target="_top" to the link in interactive_sverige.htm do the trick?

So in your iframe:

```
<a href="foo.html" target="_top">Foo</a>
```