# Facebook invite friends doesn't work on native android browser

Tags: javascript, facebook, mobile

I am developing facebook mobile web app, I tested invite friends on all desktop browsers and it works fine, it is also works fine on firefox for mobile. But it is not working on android native browser, the invite friends popup appears and only shows loading process.

here is my code:

```
function sendRequestInvite() {
FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    suggestions: nonAppFriendIDs,
    message: 'Learn how to make your mobile web app social',
}, function(response) {

    console.log('sendRequestInvite UI response: ', response);
});
```

}

could you please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After one month, I found the answer, it is really simple and I was completely chocked when I figured it out.
It only needs to add title to the FB.ui, so the new code will look like this:

```
function sendRequestInvite() {
        FB.ui({
            method: 'apprequests',
            title : 'any title'
            message: 'Learn how to make your mobile web app social',
            }, function(response) {
         });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my application (which uses Facebooks JS-SDK) using Android KitKat 4.4's default Chrome browser.

When you connect your mobile device to the PC and use it to debug the page (same thing you do in Chrome's developer page; Steps to do this can be found on [Chrome's Remote Debugging page](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging)) you might see an error (much as I did) which states

> Refused to display 'https://m.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?access_token=foobar3Dparent%26frame%3Dfffed9438%26result%3D%2522xxRESULTTOKENxx%2522&sdk=joey' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

If this is indeed the error you see, have a look at [Overcoming “Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options) and [how to force link from iframe to be opened in the parent window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037839/how-to-force-link-from-iframe-to-be-opened-in-the-parent-window) StackOverflow threads.

If the X-Frame-Option DENY might or might not be your issue but the key is to get Chrome debugging enabled because at least you'll be able to see Facebook JS-SDK based issues in the Console.