# A part of a website in an iframe, how to open it's links in the parent's window?

Tags: html, iframe

I have the following code to insert a part of a website via an iframe on my webpage:

```
<iframe  scrolling="no" frameBorder="0"
  src="http://www.dn.se/" 
  style="width:100%; height:150px; border:none;">
</iframe>
```

I would like to open *all* links on the "iframed" website in my webpage's window (and not in the iframe). I have read on [SO questions like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037839/how-to-force-link-from-iframe-to-be-opened-in-the-parent-window), that I should use:

```
<base target="_parent" />
```

But I don't seem to get it right.

**How can I open all links in a iframe window in it's parent's window, if it's a website I'm iframing?**

(If possible I don't want to use a javascript library like jQuery.)

Answer (score 0):

If your website and the iFrame are not on the same domain name, the browser will not allow this.

It's called Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)

Comment: So programmatically setting the target attribute with javascript on every link would be the only way?