# How to open a new window from Google Maps iFrame?

Tags: iframe, google-maps

I have created a Google Maps map that I included on a webpage, by following these steps:

1. click "Customize and preview embedded map"
2. adjust the preview
3. copy paste the URL under "Paste HTML to embed in website"
4. paste the copied code into our webpage (`<iframe>`)

Now when clicking an area that I have created within the map (draw a shape) the user is able to click a link that points to another page within our website. But, the problem is that the page opens in the same `<iframe>`, whilst it should open outside the `<iframe>`.

When adding attributes like `target="_blank"` or `target="_top"` the attribute is stripped away by Google when saving the maps. Hence my embedded Google Maps map is useless for my website visitors.

Does anybody know how to make sure the window is opened outside the `<iframe>`?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using the `base` tag within the `<iframe>`?

```
<base target="_parent" />
```

See [How to force link from iframe to be opened in the parent window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037839/how-to-force-link-from-iframe-to-be-opened-in-the-parent-window).

Alternatively you could create a intermediary page that the Google Maps page can call with a URL in the querystring that then runs some JavaScript to redirect the parent page to the URL.