# Opening new window in iframe from bing search results

Tags: iframe, sandbox, bing

I am heading to the following problem:

I've implemented a bing search into a website and when i submit my search query i open a dialog, in this dialog in an iframe my search results appear. How can i manage that when i click on the search results, a new window opens and and not in the current iframe. I've search for this problem and found that i should set the sandbox attributes. Well i did so but still it doesn't open the sites in a new window.

```
<iframe src="http://www.bing.com/search?cp=1252=&amp;q=Manchester United" id="searchresults" border="0" width="980" height="700" frameborder="0" sandbox=""></iframe>
```

It would be great if someone can help me out with this issue.

Comment: This question might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037839/how-to-force-link-from-iframe-to-be-opened-in-the-parent-window