# app android - external resources implementation

Tags: javascript, android, html, rest

I'm developing an Android / iOS app for a local taxi service. 
What they ask is to also have trains, flights and ferries schedules implemented in the app. Unfortunately none of those is available via API restful / web service (Italy). So what I thought was to develop an hybrid html5 / javascript app (then have it built as native with intel xdk) and simply use an iframe tag for every resource I need (however not liking the idea and knowing that it would imply some drawbacks, not the least of which, having to bring in the whole website of every resource I need, with no control of any content whatsoever ). The major issue now is: every time I click on a menu item the internal browser seems to open a new window, so if I am on the 'trains', then go check 'flights' , 'trains' remains open in background. If I click 'trains' again on the menu I'm actually opening one more window on top of the two, and so on. Result: 5 / 6 clicks and there's too much stuff bubbled up and it all goes quirky!

```
    <div class="panel" title="Pisa-Airport" id="page4" data-footer="none">
        <header>
            <a id="menubadge" onclick='$.ui.toggleSideMenu()' class='menuButton' style="float:left !important"></a>
            <h1>Pisa Airport</h1>
        </header>
        <iframe src="http://m.pisa-airport.com/index.php?lang=_it&step=1"></iframe>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add base tag target as parent in iFrame head.

[StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037839/how-to-force-link-from-iframe-to-be-opened-in-the-parent-window)

```
<base target="_parent" />
```