# Detect iframe link click and open it as main window

Tags: html, iframe

I have two page index.html and my.html
the my.html will appear as iframe in index.html
and in my.html will a link, if any one click the link `http://www.swisteronline.in` need to open. I do it, but the page `http://www.swisteronline.in` is opening in iframe in place of my.hml. but i need to open the site in place of index.html what to do?

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="my.html" height="100%" width="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0">`</iframe>`
</body>
</html>
```

**my.html**

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="http://www.swisteronline.in">Click here to go</a>
</body>
```

I need to open `http://www.swisteronline.in` when anyone clicke on "**Click here to go**" in place of index.html. I can only open it in place of my.html
what to do? please help... thanks

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037839/how-to-force-link-from-iframe-to-be-opened-in-the-parent-window

Answer (score 0):

Add `target="_parent"` in anchor tag inside my.html

```
<a href="http://www.swisteronline.in" target="_parent">Click here to go</a>
```