# Payment Gateway call back URL loads in the Iframe itslef

Tags: angular, angular7

We need to use EVO for payment in Angular 7 application.

Evo pages will be loaded inside an iframe as follows.

```html
<iframe id="iframe_id" 
      style="border: 0px" 
      width="100%" height="600px" 
      [src]="url" 
      (load)="iframeContentLoaded()"
      scrolling="no">
</iframe>
```

We have to provide success and cancel URLs for this EVO. Once EVO processing has completed, it redirects to success URL, however the success url is being loaded in the iframe.

for example:

successUrl: http://localhost:4200/autoinsurance/#success
cancelUrl: http://localhost:4200/autoinsurance/#failure

Now success route component will be loaded in the iframe itself, however we need to load outside of that iframe.

Could somebody provide suggestion to achieve it?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2656798/3371440.

Comment: I added the following code in my index.html as it is an angular application. <base target="_parent" href="/autoinsurance" />  It did not work. Still success/return url is loading in the iframe itself.