# When I open a new tab from a link inside an iframe open a page with the iframe embedded

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a page with an embedded iframe. Currently if a user were to open a new tab from a link inside that iframe (either by right clicking on it or clicking while holding ctrl or cmd) it will open a tab with the iframe's url and will no longer be embedded.

For example if I had youtube.com in an iframe and were to right click on an element inside the iframe and open a new tab I want the new tab to have my website with youtube.com still embedded. But currently the behavior is to just open a new tab with youtube.com.

I have tried target="_parent", but that didn't help.

Comment: Duplication -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037839/how-to-force-link-from-iframe-to-be-opened-in-the-parent-window

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force link from iframe to be opened in the parent window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037839/how-to-force-link-from-iframe-to-be-opened-in-the-parent-window)