# R shiny app embedded using iframe. How to set links to open outside the iframe?

Tags: r, iframe, shiny

I have created a shiny app, deployed it on my server, and embedded it within an iFrame on another website. In the shiny app, I have some really basic HTML links that users can click to find out more information on things within the shiny app.

E.g. `<a href='url' target='_blank'>More Info</a>`

When viewing the embedded app, clicking will open the new link within the iframe. Instead, I would like for users to be able to click the link and have their whole browser window be redirected.

I'm more familiar with R but pretty new to creating websites, so any suggestions would be appreciated, either on changes within the shiny app or on the website side where the app is embedded.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2656798/9841389) you can
add `<base target="_parent">` to the head of the page in the iframe to open the links in the parent window or `<base target="_blank">` to open them in a new window.

Here is a `shiny` example:

```
library(shiny)

if(!dir.exists("myhtmlcontent")){
  dir.create("myhtmlcontent")
}

writeLines(text = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<base target="_blank">
</head>
<body>
<a href="https://www.r-bloggers.com/">Visit r-bloggers.com</a>
</body>
</html>', "myhtmlcontent/iframe_content.html")

addResourcePath("myhtmlcontent", "myhtmlcontent")

ui <- fluidPage(
  # tags$head(tags$base(target="_blank")), # to be used when showing this shiny app in an iframe
  tags$iframe(src="myhtmlcontent/iframe_content.html", height = 600, width = 600)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```